# Fill UITableCellView with a uibutton

Tags: uitableview, uibutton

My goal is insert in a cell of grouped tableview a button that is perfectly fill it, like facebook or skype login on iPad. To do this I use this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Login";
  UITableViewCell* cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if(cell == nil){
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0){
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setFrame:cell.frame];
    [button setTitle:@"Do Stuff" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:button];
  }
  return cell;
}
```

But the result is this:

[image: UIButton on cell of tableview]

is not what i wanted, the button is wider than cell and its position is incorrect.
I solved doing various tests to find the right values ​​for the frame of the button, but I think this is not the best and most elegant solution. Does anyone have a better solution than mine?

Instead with this code:

```
if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0){
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setFrame:cell.bounds];//note here bounds
    [button setTitle:@"Do Stuff" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
}
  return cell;
```

the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct answer. The key is to set the autoresizingMask as shown in following code sample.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString* CellIdentifier = nil;
    if (indexPath.section == BTNSCTN && indexPath.row == BTNROW) {
        CellIdentifier = @"ButtonCell";
        UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   // autorelease if not using ARC

            UIButton* buttonUp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [buttonUp setTitle:@"Shake it up!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [buttonUp addTarget:self action:@selector(shakePhone)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            buttonUp.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;   // or cell.bounds
            buttonUp.autoresizingMask =
            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:buttonUp];
        }
        return cell;
    }
    else
        // handle the other sections and cells...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Login";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0){
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];//note here
        [button setFrame:cell.bounds];//note here bounds
        [button setTitle:@"Do Stuff" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        cell.clipsToBounds=YES;//note here



        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];//note here contentview
    }


    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The vertex at the top left of the button coincides with that of the cell, but is still larger than the cell. In my question i changed the image with one more meaningful.

Comment: pls post as image what u need as final result

Comment: the result is the same. if you sety a background color to the button you can see that is more larger of the cell

Comment: The problem is that when call [button setFrame:cell.bounds] return value for plain table so the width of the button will be more than the cell of grouped table; so we should calculate the margins and subtract.